# How to read name-value attributes from an app.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am able to read the key-value attributes from the `app.config` file by using the following syntax.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigurationFile"]
```

I want to read the name-value attributes from the `app.config` file which are defined under the following schema.

```
    <applicationsettings>
        <Host.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Path" serializeAs="String">
                <value>F:\PATH\</value>
            </setting>
        <Host.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

What is the correct solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"]
```

or this:

```
Host.Properties.Settings.Default.Path
```

should work.

Comment: @mservidio It works out for key-value attributes but not for the name-value attributes.

Comment: Host.Properties.Settings.Default.Path should work for name-value attributes. I might not be understanding your question, could you clarify?

Comment: I did use the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["Path"]. I am reading the values into some text boxes. As all values are under appsettings i am able to read them.  But now i want to read the values into the textboxes from the part of the config file i mentioned above in the actual question .

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the values that you want to read into your textboxes out of the config file? Your question isn't completely clear on which part of the app.config file you want to read into the textboxes. From my understanding, you want name-value pairs, in your case it would be name = path and value = F:\PATH\. Which values are you trying to get from the file?

Comment: I am trying to get the value "F:\Path\" from the config file into the textbox.

Comment: Host.Properties.Settings.Default.Path should return back the value "F:\Path\". What is it returning for you?